# Publishing a shared appsettings file with .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a .net core solution that contains a database project (class library) and a console application. The database project contains EF Migrations and to do `Add-Migration`, most methods use a hard-coded connection string in one place or the other.

To avoid hard-coding (and/or duplication) I have created a shared `appsettings.json` file in the solution root and I use it in my `Main` method and the class library

In the console application

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var settingPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(@"../appsettings.json"));

    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile(settingPath, false);

    var configuration = builder.Build();

    var services = new ServiceCollection()           
        .AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(configuration["ConnectionStrings:MyDatabase"]))  
        .BuildServiceProvider();
}
```

And in the class library to use migrations

```
public class DesignTimeDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyContext>
{
    public MyContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var settingPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(@"../appsettings.json"));

        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile(settingPath, false);

        var configuration = builder.Build();

        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>()
            .UseSqlServer(configuration["ConnectionStrings:MyDatabase"]);

        return new MyContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

This is working well for development purposes when I use `dotnet run` but when I publish the console application, it doesn't include the appsettings file. Other than running a powershell script as part of `dotnet publish`, is there any other cleaner way of including this file when the project is published?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` is exactly for the purpose its name describes. You shouldn't be running migrations against your production database in the first place, and if you do, you should be generating specific migrations for production into your app (instead of the class library) and using your app for the migrations. See the [docs on using a separate project for migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/projects). That, then, negates the need to share your appsettings.json. Just leave the connection string hard-coded in your factory, since it's only for development anyways.

Now, you might have an issue I suppose in a team environment. However, even if you're using something like SQLite, you can use project-relative paths that won't be developer-specific, and with LocalDB, you can use a normal SQL Server connection string to the MSSQLLocalDB instance, which will be same for every developer using Visual Studio. Regardless, even if you do need to specify the connection specifically by developer, at that point it would make more sense to use user secrets, anyways, since you wouldn't want that info be committed to source control. Otherwise, each developer would end up clobbering the other's copy of appsettings.json, and you'd have a mess on your hands.

Long and short, just hard-code the connection string in your factory, or if you can't or won't, use user secrets for the connection string. In either case, you do not need to share appsettings.json.

Comment: `You shouldn't be running migrations against your production database in the first place` - You're saying I shouldn't generate the migrations from production, right? Not that I shouldn't be using migrations to upgrade the schema in production? Wouldn't I need to be able to run `Update-Database` when doing a release? What would be the best way to specify a connection string at that time?

Comment: Both. Applying schema updates to a production database should be part of your release pipeline, and you should be done by a DBA or an automated tool specifically designed for the purpose of migrating database schemas in production. The EF Core CLI commands are far too naive to be used reliably in a production environment.

Comment: Something like [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johanclasson.UpdateDatabaseWithDbUp)?

Comment: I suppose. I haven't used that specifically, but the idea is that you want versioned SQL scripts involved. You should always know and understand exactly what is going to be run against your production database. More advanced solutions generally also involve things like incremental backup and restore functonality, etc. The idea is that you need an end-to-end solution that not only supports change your database schema but also rolling forward or backward when things blow up.

Comment: Hey, just a quick follow up. I have been re-reading some material around this and the consensus seems to be that using `dbcontext.database.migrate()` on app startup is a valid way to do migrations in production. Does this conflict with `The EF Core CLI commands are far too naive to be used reliably in a production environment` or was that only about the powershell `Update-Database` and entityframework's `dotnet ef database update`?

Comment: That's essentially the same. I'm not sure where you found that "consensus", but that's actually worse in a way. Just like you should do an automated build as part of a software release, there should be an automated build of your database as well, that essentially entails updating the schema against a facsimile to ensure that the update succeeds without issue. Again, the better tools provide this type of functionality. Waiting until your app is actually running in production makes recovering difficult.

Comment: Imagine a scenario where you deploy your app. *Then*, the schema is updated, but the update fails. Now you have a broken application in production. Your only choice at that point is to roll back your app code, which isn't always easy, or roll forward, which could mean an extended period of downtime. Long and short, you don't want to wait until after deployment to find out there's database issues.

Comment: Yeah, I do get your logic (and maybe that's why I'm confused). [This MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-dotnetcore-sqldb#connect-to-sql-database-in-production) for example shows something similar. And so does [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/index#automatically-upgrading-on-application-startup-migratedatabasetolatestversion-initializer).

Comment: 1) There&#39;s an impetus in Core to compete with other big name frameworks: Ruby on Rails, Django, etc. Those often have functionality such as this. (FWIW, that's also a large part of the reason it took enterprise so long to embrace them.) 2) The marketing department holds a lot of sway, cf. Razor Pages. There&#39;s value to Microsoft in selling web application development as something you can do in an afternoon. While that's kind of true, such apps aren't truly production worthy. 3) Some apps don't warrant full scale build and release pipelines...

Comment: If you're just throwing up your personal blog, maybe migrating on startup isn't such an issue. For a large scale enterprise class app, it very much is. As someone who's been building web apps in one form or another for the past decade and a half, believe me when I say that it's worth every ounce of over-cautiousness if you've ever spent 72 hours straight fixing a blown deployment.

Comment: Agreed. Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 0):

The way I've done this before is to specify the startup project when you run `dotnet ef` (with the `-s` switch - the options are at `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet#common-options`)

It gets messy quickly, and it's probably easiest to write some wrapper scripts for the project that deal with this kind of thing.